# ANT how to execute a JAR or EXE files on a specific folder

Tags: ant

I have a POS software (Point Of Sale) runs on ANT, never worked on ant so please if possible provide full code to run either an EXE or a JAR executable file on a specific location.

I have those following codes and no use:

```
<target name="build">
<java fork="true" failonerror="yes" classname="com.CodeReview">
<classpath>
   <pathelement location="xyz"/>
   <pathelement path="${C:/xyz.jar}"/>
 </classpath>
<arg line="-p"/>
<arg line="D:\Test"/>
</java>
</target>
```

PS: First code gave this error:

com.openbravo.pos.scripting.ScriptException: 
Encountered ":/xyz.jar}\"/>\n \n\n ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the ${ and } around C:/xyz.jar, which should not be there because C:/xyz.jar is a literal and not the name of a property whose value you want to use.

If you defined a property like this:

```xml
<property name="path.to.xyz.jar" value="C:/xyz.jar"/>
```

...then you could later reference it like this:

```xml
<pathelement path="${path.to.xyz.jar}"/>
```

Otherwise, to insert the value directly without using a property, the ${ and the } must be removed:

```xml
<pathelement path="C:/xyz.jar"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't work, no error output nothing... anyway thanks for the help

Comment: if not asking for too much could you post full document code maybe am missing something...

Comment: You can find several examples in the "Examples" section of the Ant "java" task documentation: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html  (The exact parameters depend on what exactly you're trying to run.)